# iPhone:Upload image on Instagram

Tags: iphone, ios6, instagram, uidocument

I have written the code to upload image on instagram which is as follows:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(20 ,20 , 200, 200);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *jpgPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"after2sm.ig"];

    NSString *fileURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@",jpgPath];
    NSURL *igImageHookFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileURL];

    self.dic.UTI = @"com.instagram.photo";

    self.dic = [self setupControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile usingDelegate:self];
    self.dic=[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile];

    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"My Caption" forKey:@"InstagramCaption"];
    [self.dic presentOpenInMenuFromRect:rect inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

But it opens a actionsheet with "instagram" option but when i click on that nothing happens..can you please help me

Comment: I want to upload image on instagram

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this ,
In this code set your image in imgUpload object

```
    - (IBAction)InstagramButtonClick
   { 

        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 612, 612);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
        [imgUpload drawInRect:rect];

        UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        NSString  *savePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/test.igo"];
        [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0) writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];

        NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"file://%@", savePath]];


        self.dic.UTI = @"com.instagram.photo";
        self.dic = [self setupControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile usingDelegate:self];

        self.dic=[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile];
          self.dic.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"your message" forKey:@"InstagramCaption"];
        [self.dic presentOpenInMenuFromRect: CGRectZero    inView: self.view animated: YES ];

    }
```

//Add the delegate `UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate` and following is a delegate method

```
- (UIDocumentInteractionController *) setupControllerWithURL: (NSURL*) fileURL usingDelegate: (id <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>) interactionDelegate {
        UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: fileURL];
        interactionController.delegate = interactionDelegate;
        return interactionController;

}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But I get the same result with your code.

Comment: image size should be more than 620*620

Comment: and ya check intstagram app should be installed in device. it is necessary

Comment: My image is of size 650 *650 and instagram app is installed in device

Comment: How to generate test.igo file?

Comment: did you add delegate UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate in .h file ?

Comment: is your delegate method called ?

Comment: [imgUpload drawInRect:rect]; In this "imgUpload" is not defined. So actually what it is?

Comment: this is your image which you want to upload. set it

Comment: you should set that otherwise nothing will happen